# Remove White Space From Text that i scraped from website

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to scrape a list of medicines from a website. 
I am using JSOUP to parse the Html.

Here is my code :

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.medindia.net/drug-price/index.asp?alpha=a");
Document doc1 = Jsoup.parse(url, 0);

Elements rows = doc1.getElementsByAttributeValue("style", "padding-left:5px;border-right:1px solid #A5A5A5;");

for(Element row : rows){
    String htm = row.text();
    if(!(htm.equals("View Price")||htm.contains("Show Details"))) {
        System.out.println(htm);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Here is the Output that I am getting:

[image: Output Image]

P.S. *This is not the complete output* But As I couldn't Take The Screen Shot of the complete output, I just displayed it.

I need to Know Two Things :

**Question 1.** Why am I getting an Extra Space In front of each Drug Name and why am I getting Extra New Line After Some Drug's Name?

**Question 2.** How do I resolve this Issue?

Comment: Use .trim() to remove unwanted whitespaces from beginning and end.

Comment: @specialscope its not removing the space, IDK why!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

1. It's not the complete output because there's more than one page. I put a `for` loop that fixes that for you.
2. You should probably trim the output using `htm.trim()`
3. You should probably make sure to not print when there's a newLine (`!htm.isEmpty()`)
4. That website has a weird character with ASCII value 160 in it. I added a small fix that solves the problem. (with `.replace`)

Here's the fixed code:

```
for(char page='a'; page <= 'z'; page++) {
  String urlString = String.format("http://www.medindia.net/drug-price/index.asp?alpha=%c", page);
  URL url = new URL(urlString);
  Document doc1 = Jsoup.parse(url, 0);
  Elements rows = doc1.getElementsByAttributeValue("style", "padding-left:5px;border-right:1px solid #A5A5A5;");
  for(Element row : rows){
    String htm = row.text().replace((char) 160, ' ').trim();
    if(!(htm.equals("View Price")||htm.contains("Show Details"))&& !htm.isEmpty())
    {
      System.out.println(htm.trim());
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I know its not the complete output because right now i am not able to process the values for Alpha = a, whats the point processing all of them till z. 
Also Your Code Doesn't Seem to solve the problem. I tried it.

Comment: I don't have JSoup installed on this computer. What exactly goes wrong? Can you explain better which elements aren't being printed?

Comment: Before Each Drug Name there is a Space and After Certain Names There is an Extra Line Printed, and that line has nothing but just one whitespace character, I am sure This is due to &nbsp; but i am not able to remove it.

Comment: But it isn't fixing it. I have tried with your code, as well as made the fixes in my code as well. 
Is there any other way to scrape these values from the Website.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20758/discussion-between-ishan-khanna-and-durron597)

Comment: @IshanKhanna I fixed it, see the line with `.replace((char) 160, ' ')` in it

Comment: It solves 1 Problem, The space from The Front has been removed, but it still prints an extra line.

Comment: No, it doesn't, I installed JSoup and tested it. Use my code exactly, don't modify yours. Wait, are you talking about the single extra line between each medicine?

Comment: Extra line is Not between each medicine, but after some medicines, The medicines that are displayed in black colour on the website.

Answer (score 1):

Do one thing :

Use trim function in syso : `System.out.println(htm.trim());`

**UPDATED :**

After a lot of effort I was able to parse all 80 medicines like this :-

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.medindia.net/drug-price/index.asp?alpha=a");
Document doc1 = Jsoup.parse(url, 0);
Elements rows = doc1.select("td.ta13blue");
Elements rows1 = doc1.select("td.ta13black.tbold");
int cnt=0;
for(Element row : rows){
    cnt++;
    String htm = row.text().trim();
    if(!(htm.equals("View Price")||htm.contains("Show Details") || htm.startsWith("Drug"))) {
        System.out.println(cnt+" : "+htm);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
for(Element row1 : rows1){
    cnt++;
    String htm = row1.text().trim();
    if(!(htm.equals("View Price")||htm.contains("Show Details") || htm.startsWith("Drug"))) {
        System.out.println(cnt+" : "+htm);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: If i use Class = ta13blue, it will skip all the elements of class = ta13black bold. So i don't think your code would solve the issue.

Comment: Atndrea Ligios is right changing style to class worked like charm..See the updated answer..

Comment: what do you mean by Drug Here ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20759/discussion-between-ishan-khanna-and-abhi-mishra)

Answer (score 0):

1) Taking elements by *style* is quite dangerous;

2) Calling ROWS what instead is a list of FIELDS is even more dangerous :)

3) Opening the page , you can see that the extra lines are added ONLY after "black names", name of items not wrapped in an anchor link.

You problem is then that the second field in that rows is not `Show Details` nor `View Price` and not even empty... it is:

```
<td bgcolor="#FFFFDB" align="center" 
    style="padding-left:5px;border-right:1px solid #A5A5A5;">
         &nbsp;
</td>
```

It is a one space string. Modify your code like this:

```
for(Element row : rows){
    String htm = row.text().trim(); // <!-- This one
    if(!
         (htm.equals("View Price") 
          || htm.contains("Show Details")
          || htm.equals("&nbsp;")) // <!-- And this one
       ) {
        System.out.println(htm);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is an alternative to do this?